# How to change Asp.net .cs file path

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am newbie with asp.net. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 to write my codes. How can I change the ".cs" file location ? because I need to send my application to someone else. The issue starts when I put ".cs" file in a 1 folder. When ".cs" file on my desktop the application works.

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution for this problem.

Do this following steps :
1)Go to the file which appears as Miscellaneous Files inside Solution Explorer.
2)Right-Click file and select Exclude from project.
3)Right-Click your project/folder where the file was and click add Existing Item, and add the file you just removed back into your project